# Evaluating country-level indicators through ROC analysis

Tags: predictive-models, roc, auc

Good afternoon.

I  have defined a binary classification problem. Classes are based on country-level data on child undernourishment whereby a positive class is assigned to a country whenever it performs above the world median and a negative otherwise. Now, the predictor for these classes is not a **model** but an indicator. In particular, I want to evaluate how well cumulative expenditure on early education *predicts* child undernourishment. So, in this setting I have positive integers, i.e. the total sum of moneys spent on early education,  to predict binary classes, i.e whether a country is above or below the world median.. I would normally, as a first step, do = a basic ROC analysis and evaluate performance through the AUC.

It is obvious that such a broad issue is unlikely to be determined by a single indicator, and that the ideas has many methodological issues, but I have reasons to believe it has some merit.

In some cases I am seeing AUCs below 0.5. Now, when faced with this problem I would look carefully at the data, and think about what could be happening and, if conditions allow, reverse the labels. Otherwise, I would try some debiasing or look at the model more carefully and see why this could be happening.

The literature deals with this problem at length. Two very cool references on the topic

- Jamalabadi et al. [Classification based hypothesis testing in neuroscience: Below‐chance level classification rates and overlooked statistical properties of linear parametric classifiers](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/hbm.23140).
- Snoek et al. [How to control for confounds in decoding analyses of neuroimaging data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30268846).

In this case, however, I am hesitant to even analyse the matter further. I would like to conclude that AUCs below 0.5 are signalling that the indicator is not much of a predictor in the context of this classification problem.

The question is then:

Does this make any sense?

I was really not able to find a pertinent reference in the literature on on stackoverflow. Now, this could mean two things: a. the idea is rubbish, or b. I am an absolute genius. I am currently favouring option a.

Thank you!

Comment: A couple of comments: a) the total sum of moneys spent on early education doesn't take into account how many children a country has to raise and educate. b) Why do you need to create (artificially) a binary classification problem? You could look at childhood undernourishment as a function of spending on early education. c) It may be easy to find additional information about the socioeconomic development of countries, so that you can build a better model.

Comment: Thank you for your comment a) these indicators are really “excess child undernourishment” that is in relation to previous years and presented as percentages. I should have clarified this in the question. b)correlations are normally really poor, as these are multifactorial problems, so there’s really little signal. This is mainly what drew me to this artificial classification. People assume that this should have mayor effects,  but there’s little in proving. c)yes..I am doing some I am doing some  GLMM but there is little signal with known related indicators.

Comment: Under or over the world median is not a good way to conceptualize the problem and results in a loss of information and difficult-to-interpret results due to hidden heterogeneity within nourishment "groups".  Nourishment is a continuous quantity.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Harrell. I completely agree, this is an extremely limited approach.I have created groupings based on income level, geographic location, and a few other groups, in an attempt to capture some of this heterogeneity. In every case resultas are the same. Would you have any advise? There does not seem to be a strong signal in general. There does not seem to be any agreement in the literature on how to evaluate this. They resort to ranks, but they do not indicate “conmensurability” with resources.